# How to add 5 Textboxes and 1 button to GridView in footer ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Like in title? have no idea how to do it

I wrote something like this:

```
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
          <FooterTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" />
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" />
              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" />
          </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="False" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="something" HeaderText="something" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="country" HeaderText="country" />
          <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>
```

but it gives me extra column i want to add this textbox in the column that already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

That is how.

Comment: but it's give me extra columns i have a columns and want to add 1 textbox to exist column in footer and next textbox to another exist column any idea?

Comment: You have to place the Textbox in each Template Field.`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>`

Answer (score 2):

Set ShowFooter To true for your GridView and define FooterTemplate for whichever column you would like the footer to be shown and add the 5 Textboxes and 1 Button to this template section.